# Flink scala Case class

Tags: scala, class, apache-flink

I want to know how to replace x._1._2, x._1._3  by the name of the field using case class

```
def keyuid(l:Array[String]) : (String,Long,String) ={
  //val l=s.split(",")
  val ip=l(3).split(":")(1)
  val values=Array("",0,0,0)
  val uid=l(1).split(":")(1)
  val timestamp=l(2).split(":")(1).toLong*1000
  val impression=l(4).split(":")(1)
  return (uid,timestamp,ip)
}

val cli_ip = click.map(_.split(","))
  .map(x => (keyuid(x), 1.0)).assignAscendingTimestamps(x=>x._1._2)
  .keyBy(x => x._1._3)
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10))
  .sum(1)
```

Comment: Do you mean Tuples (String, Long, String) ? I can't really see here some case classes

Comment: Actually I want to make the code more readable , so I want to replace x._1._2 and x._1._3 ( ip in my case ) by the naame of the field . Is it possible for the function keyuid to return a case class ?

Comment: Got it. Yes, you can pack all three fields in your-defined case class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern Matching is indeed a good idea and makes the code more readable.
To answer your question, to make keyuid function returns a case class, you first need to define it, for instance :

case class Click(string uid, long timestamp, string ip)

Then instead of `return (uid,timestamp,ip)` you need to do `return Click(uid,timestamp,ip)`

Case class are not related to flink, but to scala : https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Scala pattern matching when writing lambda functions using curly braces and `case` keyword.

```
val cli_ip = click.map(_.split(","))
  .map(x => (keyuid(x), 1.0)).assignAscendingTimestamps { 
    case ((_, timestamp, _), _) => timestamp 
  }
  .keyBy { elem => elem match {
      case ((_, _, ip), _) => ip
    }
  }
  .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10))
  .sum(1)
```

More information on Tuples and their pattern matching syntax here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tuples.html

Comment: Thanks a lot , However  I had a problem "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'keyBy' ".

Comment: Your are right. `keyBy` combinator is a bit tricky and has a couple of overloaded options. I  have added the pattern matching clause into the lambda body. See updates above.